# How to add profile with updated field permissions in package.xml?

Tags: deployment, xml

I want to update a profile with some field level permissions and then deploy this on another sandbox. How can I add this in package.xml?

Below is the sample XML Code for this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>Deployment1</fullName>
    <description>Deploy Profile updates</description>
    <types>
        <members>CustomObject1__c.CustomField1__c</members>
        <members>CustomObject1__c.CustomField2__c</members>
        <members>CustomObject2__c.CustomField1__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <version>48.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deploy profile changes to the production?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/150671/how-to-deploy-profile-changes-to-the-production)

Comment: Are you using the SFDX CLI or the VS Code plugins for example?

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you just need to include the Profile in your package. Then when you retrieve the package, the Profile will be truncated to only include those fields and the base aspects of the Profile.

If you don't want to include those, you can remove them manually but if you haven't changed anything else you will be able to just deploy that package to the next environment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>Deployment1</fullName>
    <description>Deploy Profile updates</description>
    <types>
        <members>CustomObject1__c.CustomField1__c</members>
        <members>CustomObject1__c.CustomField2__c</members>
        <members>CustomObject2__c.CustomField1__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>ChangedProfile</members>
        <name>Profile</name>
    </types>
    <version>58.0</version>
</Package>
```

Just a note with the truncation of the Profile, this is due to Salesforce doing some work in the background to try and reduce the risk of you accidentally changing other aspects of the profile when you deploy. This means that it will only retrieve permissions for objects and fields that are explicitly being retrieved or deployed at the same time.

Also another note, you should update the API version of your package as well as 48.0 is significantly out of date at this point and would mean any new metadata attributes in a newer version wouldn't be deployed or retrieved.